# Простенький вопрос по If, else

Tags: php, if

Есть следующий код:

```
  if ...
    $users = User::all()
  else
    $users = User::where()
```

Как сделать так, чтобы if проверка была внутри **User::**(if something 'all' else 'where') ...

Спасибо всем заранее за отклик.

Comment: Сделать отдельный метод можно внутри которого реализуется if или тернарник..... можно сразу тернарником... а вот так `User::(if something 'all' else 'where')` писать - не стОит. Это плохой код.....в целом и текущий код плохой.... он очень странный

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь этим решить? Какой framework используете? Очень похоже на laravel

Comment: Можно пример, пожалуйста?

Comment: White Marlin, да, это фреймворк Laravel. Я хочу сделать условие, чтобы админу показалось all() а пользователям where()

Comment: Правильно будет не ИФать, а делать два экшна, которые отвечают за две разные операции......... а ещё правильнее было бы разделить операции для админа и для пользователя...это вообще должны быть два разных контроллера, а то и модуля

Comment: Почему так считаете?

Comment: "считаете" - это когда высказано мнение, а тут чёткая констатация факта на основе опыта, принятых практик, и, как минимум, самых предлагаемых подходов фреймворка у которого (шок контент!!!) есть методы index, update, show, create, delete и прочие разделения по ответственности